# How to type a variable and have it read as normal text

Tags: python, variables

How can I type a variable and have it read as normal text?

For example

```
small_font = pie game.Font.System_Font('a type of font', 25)
size = 'small'
text_surface = size_font.render(text, True, color)
```

How do I have my computer read **size**`_font.render.....` as **small**`_font.render.....`

**SUMMARY**

I have these at the top

```
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25) 
medimfont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 50) 
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 80)
```

what i want is to make my my computer read size_font.render..... as small_font.render.....

Comment: first line should be like this:
small_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your function as attribute of module:

```py
import sys

small_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25) 
size = 'small'
text_surface = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "{0}_font".format(size)).render(text, True, color)
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, but
is there a way to use it without importing sys?
and what if I have ```small_font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25)``` in a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access different variables/objects according to the value of a string, the standard solution is to use a dictionary. For instance:

```
fonts = {}
fonts['small'] = pygame.Font.System_Font('a type of font', 10)
fonts['normal'] = pygame.Font.System_Font('a type of font', 20)
fonts['big'] = pygame.Font.System_Font('a type of font', 40)
fonts['huge'] = pygame.Font.System_Font('a type of font', 80)

# and later, use these fonts with
text_surface = fonts['small'].render(text, True, color) # use size 10 font
# or
text_surface = fonts['huge'].render(text, True, color) # use size 80 font
```

EDIT: You may also store the dictionary key in a variable:

```
size = 'small'
text_surface = fonts[size].render(text, True, color) # use size 10 font
size = 'huge'
text_surface = fonts[size].render(text, True, color) # use size 80 font
```

Comment: I have these at the top 
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25)
medimfont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 80)
what i want is to make my my computer read size_font.render..... as small_font.render.....

Comment: but can I type a variable instead of 'small' or 'huge' at the last line